# Importing old Chrome profile and all cache gets erased

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I have backed up an archived an old Chrome profile of mine - with all the cache and some bookmarks.

Just FYI on Windows Chrome profiles exist under: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

To import it what I did is create a new chrome profile, delete everything under that profile, and replace it with the contents of the backup. Now, the bookmarks and color scheme get updated successfully as well as most settings afaik - however the main thing I need, my cache is erased. Now how do I avoid this from happening? The backup is one year old if that's any help.

In case you're wondering why I need the cache, it's for some gamer IDs for online games that I have progress in.

Thanks in advance.